# Efficient query to get account balance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a  table with sample data like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/124b62

What is the best way(efficient query) to get the opening and closing balance of the cashbook account?

One way is to find total credits and subtract it from total debits.

```
SELECT sum(amount) as credit_total  
FROM `cash_book` 
WHERE `type` = 'credit' 
AND `account_holder_id` =1 
AND `created_at` >= '2016-07-31 00:00:00';


SELECT sum(amount) as debit_total
FROM `cash_book` 
WHERE `type` = 'debit' 
AND `account_holder_id` =1 
AND `created_at` >= '2016-07-31 00:00:00';
```

Can someone suggest a better query?

Comment: The idea of SO is you try and make a query you want and when you have problems you ask for help with your attempt. SO is not a free coding or code conversion service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single run total

```
SELECT sum(case when `type` = 'credit' then -amount else amount end) as total  
FROM `cash_book` 
WHERE  AND `account_holder_id` =1 and  `created_at` >= '2016-07-31 00:00:00';
```